# How can I fix this leak behind my toilet?

Tags: plumbing, leak, toilet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix this leak?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15025/how-can-i-fix-this-leak)

There's a leak in the tube behind my toilet.

[image] (see the drops of water coming out of the joint ?)

What would be the easiest way to fix that ?

Comment: Due to the staining and where the drop is, it looks like the leak may be in the pipe above this one.  Clean the pipe and wrap both pipes in paper towel.  Check them awhile later to see which one is damp to find out which pipe/joint is actually leaking.

Comment: Thx for the advice, did it and found out that it comes from a second pipe barely visible on the picture. Will create a new thread with a new picture.

Comment: @drake035 since you've found the problem is elsewhere, do you no longer need an answer to this question? If so, it should be closed or deleted. Thanks.